# Remove old artisan command by new artisan command in laravel 5.2 kernel console

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am working in kernel command where I need to change the old commands:

Old Command is:

```
php artisan crawl:author
```

Now I need to rename it like:

```
php artisan crawl-bq:author
```

In my command file signature is changed like:

protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:author';

I cleaned the artisan cache using following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Still my old command is working as well as new command is also working. But when I see the artisan list "php artisan list" then old commands are not seen there also.

Anybody there to help me?

Comment: Have you removed the command in app\Console\Kernel.php? Maybe try: `php composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen Yes, and I ran this command  php composer dump-autoload couple of times. Even I set the project up couple of times by deleting vendor folder. That means I had to run composer update and composer dump-autoload.

Comment: why don't you use an editor that has a global search feature and search your project for 'scrape:category' you probably have a remnant of it somewhere

Comment: @tam I did it already but no reference I got for the old.

Comment: does `artisan clear-compiled` change anything?

Comment: @lagbox Not actually. I ran this command but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I have come to state where I have found that Laravel 5.2 artisan console command has a bug or it is not bug as at least one command will be executed according to initial pattern matching.

Let assume, you have two signatures in two different command file like following 4 cases:

Case I:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl:author-usa';
protected $signature = 'crawl:author-uk';
```

OR Case II:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl:authorusa';
protected $signature = 'crawl:authoruk';
```

OR Case III:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:author-usa';
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:author-uk';
```

OR Case IV:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:authorusa';
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:authoruk';
```

For either case, if you run the `php artisan crawl:auther` command then for Case I, it will show the ambiguous error like:

`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "crawl:author" is ambiguous (crawl:author-usa, crawl:author-uk).`

It will show the same ambiguous message for the rest 3 cases but signature wise text would be different.

Now assume the following signature for 4 different cases:

Case I:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl:author-usa';
```

OR Case II:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl:authorusa';
```

OR Case III:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:author-usa';
```

OR Case IV:

```
protected $signature = 'crawl-bq:authorusa';
```

For either case, if you run the `php artisan crawl:auther` command, it will execute that command.

For these two scenario, it is happening because of Symfony/Cconsole find() function. Here exact command is searched by this expression : `crawl[^:]*[^:]*:author[^:]*[^:]*` . That means, if any signature has `crawl<anything>:author<anything>` will match with  `php artisan crawl:author`

Now if I come to the solution of this problem, primarily it needs to change `public function find($name)` near 509 line at [symfony/consle](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Application.php) file. Or if there is a possibility to overwrite this function ( I am not sure how this override could be done ).

I was inspired by @Nadeem0035 where he mentioned the `public function find($name)` near 509 line at [symfony/consle](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Application.php) file. I would have been happy if I could award the bounty in bounty time duration as at least he showed me a way to find exact scenario of console command. That is why a up vote dude :)

Comment: thanks :). Also share modified function when you done that.

Answer (score 1):

Old Command is:

```
php artisan crawl:author
```

Now we rename it like "crawl-bq:author"

```
php artisan crawl-bq:author (Will Work)
php artisan crawl-b:author (Will Work)
php artisan craw:author (Will Work)
php artisan crawl:author (Will Work)
```

**Solution**

Rename it with some other name like "newcrawl-bq:author"

```
php artisan crawl:author (Not work)
php artisan crawl-bq:author (Not work)
php artisan newcrawl-bq:author (Will work)
```

Comment: its ok that if I rename crawl to newcrawl-bq but I need crawl-bq. This exact thing does not work for me. And I want to make crawl-bq when crawl must not work.

Comment: I don't think its possible as you want because its default behaviors for all commands.
I don't know its bug or some thing else.
We know Actual command to create model is 
`php artisan make:model Post`

But it work with these command also
`php artisan m:model Post`
`php artisan ma:model Post`

Comment: I am also searching the command behavior as per naming convention but I did not get yet. And I am searching for any command caching but it does not exist you know.

Comment: If you want to modified default behavior then you need to change core file.

`public function find($name) { }` at line 509

[symfony/console](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Application.php)

Comment: Files under vendor folder change is not right solution as when composer update that changes would be overwritten, right?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated all the steps you mentioned and I have no problem changing signatures - Laravel doesn't seem to include artisan commands into config cache, or anywhere else for that matter. Composer dump-autoload is not relevant here if filenames remained unchanged.

The only advice I can give is to check Console/Kernel.php $commands to make sure that no duplicate commands are loaded and all signatures are as they should be. Maybe some other command is still implementing the old signature?

I realise this is an old question. Maybe you managed to solve this issue already?

Comment: I have updated my question according to as I faced very last time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the old command file from app/Console/Commands/

and this should work.